# How to get description tags from an image in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, exif

I am familiar with EXIF Tags and how to get them as a dictionary for an image. There are abundant examples on that topic. What I get is a dictionary with many items pertaining to characteristics of an image, like focus, date and time, geo data and so on. What I DO NOT GET and want to be able to read are descriptions that I assigned to an image like: "Kindergarten, Birthday party, Sailing" or whatever. These are named "Description -> Tags" if you right-click on a picture in Windows and go to the Details tab. In Adobe Bridge they are named keywords.

How can I read them in Python?

Comment: I think Adobe Bridge stores the keywords in it's own keyword file, not in the individual images. You would need to export that and then work out which keywords go with which file.

Comment: Not so. You can see those Tags when you check the file Details after right click in Windows. You can see the same keywords if you open the same image in some other photo processing software.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but [this](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html) says there is an EXIF tag named `ImageDescription` that might be what you're looking for.

PS: I'm not really sure about it so wanted to leave this as a comment...but reputation